# How can I notify a program of a hardware event?

Tags: python, c, hardware

I am looking to write a program that waits indefinitely for an event, in this case, for USB/s to be plugged in and to do some after action that.

I intend to write it in C or Python.

The question is, how can the program be notified when the event has happened (a USB device is plugged in)?

Secondly, if it were done in Python, is there a less resource-intensive way of waiting for the event besides looping?

Comment: in linux check out `udev`  , it has some example rules. `/etc/udev` should a place to start or a directory where udev conf files is located. `man udev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, you can, thanks to `udev`.

1. Identify your usb device with `udevadm info -a /dev/yourdevice`. See [Writing udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#sysfstre).
2. from your device information, create a udev rule:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="zzz", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="yyy",  RUN+="/usr/bin/my_signaler /dev/%k
   ```
3. write your signaler program (in my udev rule, it's located at `/usr/bin/my_sampler`):

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   NEW_DEVICE="$1"
   TARGETS=$(pgrep program_name)
   for proc in $TARGETS
   do
       kill -s SIGUSR1 $proc
   done
   ```
4. Make your program handle the `SIGUSR1`

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <signal.h> 
   #include <unistd.h>

   void wakeup(int sig) {
        printf("go check /dev" );
   }

   int main(void) {
       signal(SIGUSR1, wakeup);

       while (1) { 
           /* if the SIGUSR1 signal is received while sleep is waiting, sleep will return*/
           sleep(20);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: just out of curiousity, where would output from `printf()` land ? tty ? console ? file ?

Comment: In that case, in the standard output. This illustration program is to be launched from a console.

Comment: @Mathieu Hi. I've found this answer helpful except for two things: 1. Instead of printing `Go check /dev`, the console just notifies me of a `User defined signal 1`. 2. If I were to omit the ATTRS{idProduct} and ATTRS{idVendor} in the udev rule, will that make this solution general enough for all USB devices identified as sda?

Comment: @user942937 On 1., I don't know what happens, on 2., you can change `ATTRS{}==...` by `KERNEL="sda"` to match `sda`.

Comment: @Mathieu: I got it working properly now, except for every USB device plugged in, the event is triggered twice. I suspsect this might be because the USB port itself is registering an event. Also, removing the USB port triggers two additional events. Is there a way to exclude a particular device from triggering the event and to restrict the event to connecting a device?

Comment: @user942937 : Seems similar to one of my old problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253019/15601. Can you post the `udev` rule you use? I guess you need something like `ACTION=="ADD"` somewhere...

Comment: @Mathieu: the udev rule consists of only the SUBSYSTEM and RUN.

Comment: @user942937 You'd better have an `ACTION` to differentiate between plug in and out. `udevadm monitor --property` may help you